# How to properly require a file in another directory?

Tags: php

In line 3, I use the following:

```
require'./inc/connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration    file.");
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in (directory)
```

If anybody could help, this is how I have it setup.

[index.php is the file that is using the require. connection.php is in the "inc" directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU8JI.png)

Comment: `require __DIR__ . "/inc/connection.php";` and if it's still not working do `echo __DIR__ . "/inc/connection.php";` and make sure it is actually the right path.

Comment: An aside: As *require* always raises a fatal error when the file is not found, the *die* will never be called and is therefore unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have it this way, just in case if the path changes if you move the source code around.

```
$basePath = "/systemdir";
$incPath  = $basePath."/inc/";
require $incPath.'connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration file.");

require $incPath.'connection.php';
```

You really don't need a die at the end to check, php will automatically show an error if the file isn't found in that directory.

**If you're on windows, try this**

```
require __DIR__ . '/connection.php';

require 'inc/connection.php';
```

Comment: astral, are you on windows or linux?

Comment: If you're on a mac, use the command like and go to that directory. once you're there, do a pwd command and find the path. Copy the path and paste it into the code. When you find the path, directly enter the entire path into require.

Comment: @astral try require 'inc/connection.php'; try it with no ./ on windows. I'm guessing you're on index.php file?

Comment: I just require'inc/connection.php', and it just broke all the page. vobern.com is the domain if you want to see what I mean.

Comment: What's the php error. What's the content in your connection.php file? if you want to share the file, make sure you hide passwords before you post. If there are php errors on the page, the way you have your server setup it may show up as blank.

Comment: Open up your php.ini file and make sure you have display_errors = on; as a result, you can debug the issue. Restart your web server after you've made the change.

Comment: Is there any other way I can contact you besides StackOverflow?

Comment: I think there is a chat on here

Comment: @astral make sure you've enabled php error logging, otherwise you will not know what's wrong. maybe something in the configuration.php file is causing the issue. on the live server, enable php display error. you're almost there.

Comment: @astral if you still can't figure it out, you can email me at shaj.k.miah@gmail.com

Comment: I still couldnt get it to work. Ill email you right now.

Answer (score 1):

When you're including a file, you can either:

**1- Specify the full path for that file (starts with `/`)**

For example

```
require '/var/www/html/site-name/site/lib/inc/connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration    file.");
```

Notice that `/var/www/site-name/site/lib/` part? That's made up for this example. The real absolute path depends on the server and where that desired folders reside.

**2- Specify the relative path for that file (starts with a folder or file name)**

For example

```
require '../inc/connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration    file.");
```

Using the relative path means you're starting from the folder where the code actually exists. For example, the path: `'connection.php'` means `connection.php` resides in the same current folder.

The special names `.` and `..` mean current and parent directory/folders respectively. So to include a file named `connection.php` that resides in the parent folder of where the code calling it you can target it by `../connection.php`.

So, in order to fix your issue, you need to identify where is that particular file you're trying to target *relatively*. And it looks like the current path starts with `.` which means the current folder (which doesn't make sense).

An easy guess is that it was supposed to be `..` instead `.`, but not necessarily the case. The file could've been moved since that code was implemented, or a folder like `inc` name changed.

Comment: I tried this, it ended up making it to the inc, and grabbing the connection.php, but nothing happened with it.

Comment: Can you include the full path of where is that code being written and a full path for the `inc/connection.php` file? Also how did you know that the file isn't actually being included by this method and `nothing happened with it` is due to how you're testing it?

Answer (score 0):

**put two dots(..) before /inc**

Like below. use this code instead of your.

```
require '../inc/connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration    file.");
```

Comment: This still does not work, it is throwing the same error.

Comment: than check the name of connection file in inc directory.

Comment: I did, and it is all the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put two dots when you want to traverse one directory back.here you have `index.php` and `inc` in same directory so you should write

```
require 'inc/connection.php' or die ("Cannot find the proper configuration file.");
```

Comment: try giving absolute path first and if it works then change it to relative path